# Sending API request in react native after something is searched in searchbar (react-native-elements)

Tags: react-native, jsx

I have a react native search bar and I need to make an api call with the data user typed in the searchbar . but because I do not have a database on mobile device I want to make the request only if user hit search button ( not while user is typing )
and while we are on that area I also need to know how can I change the font for the placeholder in the searchbar

here is my searchbar code:

```
  <SearchBar
        placeholder="Something..."
        round
        containerStyle={{
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        width: '70%',
        borderTopWidth: 0,
        borderBottomWidth: 0
      }}
        inputContainerStyle={{
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
      }}
        cancelButtonProps={{
        color: '#fff'
      }}/>
```

Comment: You should use state for that. Set input's value to the state while user writing. `onChangeText={text => this.setState({ inputValue: text })}`. Then when user click to search button, get value of the input from state and make request.

Comment: do you know what is the best way to add search button to the searchbar ?

Comment: I guess SearchBar component is not your own. What's the package name of the `SearchBar` component? Or if it's your own, can you share the codes of component?

Comment: SearchBar from 'react-native-elements'

Comment: That's not designed with the search button. Of course you can add anywhere a custom button but I don't recommend this. That component makes you feel write and search automatically. `showLoading` props so good for that. So make request 1 seconds after user stoped the typing with SearchBar component (I recommend this). Or use Input component instead of SearchBar, then add Button and handle press event.

Comment: @akcoban it worked , thanks . post the answer if you want and I will rate it . also can you answer my second part of the question? how to change font of the placeholder

Comment: You mean fontFamily?

Comment: @akcoban yes . I can not change it in stylesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For question 1**

That's not designed with the search button. Of course you can add anywhere a custom button but I don't recommend this. That component makes you feel write and search automatically. showLoading props so good for that. So make request 1 seconds after user stoped the typing with SearchBar component (I recommend this). Or use Input component instead of SearchBar, then add Button and handle press event.

**For question 2**

I am not sure about only changing font for placeholder. But you can use inputStyle for input's font props.

```
inputStyle={{ fontWeight: '900', fontFamily: 'Roboto' }}
```

that will apply to placeholder and value of input.